# Type mismatch for function with Any* parameter

Tags: scala

I have this method:

```
private def getMachineResponse(computeFunc: (Any*) => Option[List[MyThing]], any: Any*):  Route = {
  get {
    val things = computeFunc(any)

    // now do some stuff 
  }
}
```

I would like to call this method with two different computeFunc as parameters, one with 2 arguments and the other with 4 arguments. However the calls do not compile. I am trying this:

```
getMachineResponse(computeKnownItems, 1, "s")
```

where computeKnownItems is as follows:

```
private def computeKnownItems(mtype: Int, id: String): Option[List[MyThing]] = {
  // get the things
}
```

The error is "type mismatch, found (Int, String), required (Any*)".

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying or should I make an overload for each type of computeFunc I need to pass in? (Like use (int, String) => Option[List[MyThing]] for computeFunc then create an overload that takes a computeFunc: (int, int, int, String) =>... etc)

Thank you.

Later edit: changed the parameter name to mtype (as it is in my actual code, I prettified it too much when posting here!)

Comment: Part of your problem is that your `computeFunc` is setup to be a function defined for varargs of type `Any`, but the function you are passing into `getMachineResponse` (`computeKnownItems`) is not defined to take varargs.  There is no automagical type compatibility there between essentially a `Function2[Int,String, Option[List[MyThing]]]` and `Function1[Array[Any], Option[List[MyThing]]` which your varargs defined function is

Comment: I see, thank you. I was hoping it was... e.g. in C# this can be easily done with "params". I was presuming the * and Seq are equivalents of that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all... I don't see this thing compiling. There are lots of problems other than `co-variance` and `contra-variance` issues.

Most obvious problem is here:

```
private def computeKnownItems(type: Int, id: String): Option[List[MyThing]] = {
  // get the things
}
```

No... you can not use `type` as an identifier... `type` is a keyword in Scala.

Other problem is that, something like this will not compile:

```
def simple( func: ( Int* ) => Int, ints: Int* ): Int = func( ints )

error: type mismatch;
  found   : Seq[Int]
  required: Int
    def func( ints: Int* ): Int = func( ints )
```

Neither will this:

```
def a( func: (Int*) => Int )( ints: Int* ): Int = func( ints )

error: type mismatch;
  found   : Seq[Int]
  required: Int
    def a( func: (Int*) => Int )( ints: Int* ): Int = func( ints )
                                                           ^
```

Nor will this:

```
scala> def fund( ints: Int* ): Int = ints.toList.sum
fund: (ints: Int*)Int

scala> def func( ints: Int* ): Int = fund( ints )
<console>:34: error: type mismatch;
  found   : Seq[Int]
  required: Int
    def func( ints: Int* ): Int = fund( ints )
                                        ^
```

The problem with all above was that the function was expecting multiple `Int` parameters, but was getting a single parameter which was a sequence ( `*-parameters` are implicitly received as `Seq` in function body ) . Correct way to pass vairable size parameters is following,

```
scala> def simple( func: ( Int* ) => Int, ints: Int* ): Int = func( ints: _* )
simple: (func: Int* => Int, ints: Int*)Int
```

`_*` is the special `annotation` that is usable only in arguments to `*-parameter` of a function. It makes any sequence to be passed as a `*-parameter`.

```
scala> val l = List( 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 6, 3 )
l: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 6, 3)    

scala> def pp( ints: Int* ) = println( ints )
pp: (ints: Int*)Unit

// All Int* is implicitly received as a Seq[ Int ]
// ( WrappedArray[ int ] in this case ) in function body.
scala> pp( 4, 5, 6 )
WrappedArray( 4, 5, 6 )

// Received as List[ Int ] in this case
scala> pp( l: _* )
List(4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 6, 3)

scala> def a( ints: Int* ) = ints.sum
a: (ints: Int*)Int

// passing a list wont work
scala> a( l )
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
  found   : List[Int]
  required: Int
            a( l )
               ^

// list passed as multiple parameters
scala> a( l: _* )
res8: Int = 34
```

Now, coming to main issue... seems like you are have not considered two concepts known as `co-variance` and `contra-variance`.

While both of these are very general concepts... let me explain these in reference to `types` and `classes`.

Lets say, we have two types `Animal` and `Horse` where `Horse` is a sub-type of `Animal` or `Horse <: Animal`.

Now, Lets consider a famous type - `List[ +T ]`. Now why that `+` sign... Basically that `+` indicates that `List[ T ]` is `co-variant` for `type T`, which means that if `Horse <: Animal` then `List[ Horse ] <: List[ Animal ]`. Which in turn means that you can pass an instance of `List[ Horse ]` wherever an instance of `List[ Animal ]` is required. If you think about it, it kind of true even for English.

But, if you talk about functions, they are `contra-variant`, consider `Function1[ -T, +R ]` which means that if `Horse <: Animal` then `Function1[ Animal, R ]` is a subtype of  `Function1[ Horse, R ]` or `Function1[ Animal, R ] <: Function1[ Horse, R ]`.

In your case, your type `(Any*) => Option[ List[ MyThing ] ]` is `contra-variant` wrt. its arguments which means `(int, String) => Option[ List[ MyThing ] ]` is `super-type` of `(Any*) => Option[ List[ MyThing ] ]` which again means you can not use `(int, String) => Option[ List[ MyThing ] ]` in place of `(Any*) => Option[ List[ MyThing ] ]`.

What, you can do is define functions for `Map[ String, Any ]`

```
def getMachineResponse(computeFunc: ( Map[ String, Any ] ) => Option[List[MyThing]], any: Map[ String, Any ] ):  Route = {
  get {
    val things = computeFunc(any)
    // now do some stuff 
  }
}

private def computeKnownItems(myMap: Map[ String, Any] ): Option[ List[ MyThing ] ] = {
  val myType = myMap.get( "type" ).asInstanceOf[ Int ]
  val myId = myMap.get( "id" ).asInstanceOf[ String ]
  // get the things
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct.  The `computeFunc` is defined as a `Function1` and `computeKnownItems` is a `Function2` and I think that's the real issue.

Comment: Well... I too think that the code may have some other problems... but one thing I am very much sure of is - you can not provide a `(Int*) => R` in place of `(Any*) => R`.

Comment: I am getting compilation error even with this simple thing - `def simple( func: ( Int* ) => Int, ints: Int* ): Int = func( ints )`...... `error: type mismatch;  found   : Seq[Int] ;  required: Int`.

Comment: On type being a reserved keyword, it is because I edited the actual function when I posted it here. It's called mType in my code. The error message is consistent with what cmbaxter mentioned.

Comment: Yup... as I mentioned that kind of thing does not compile. But even if it did and everything else was fixed, functions are `contra-vairant`... so it would not have worked. Your problem can be solved by using `Map[ String, Any ]` to carry your arguments.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh you just need to change from func: (Int*) to func(Seq[Int]) to get that snippet to compile (at least for me in 2.11).

Comment: Yes... that will... I was just telling about the special case of `*` as it is just syntactic sugar... but try passing a `Seq[ Int ] => R` in place of `Seq[ Any ] => R`... and you will hit a concept called `variance`.

Comment: @user2916547 I have added the info about why something like this - `def simple( func: ( Int* ) => Int, ints: Int* ): Int = func( ints )` was not working, and how to correctly fix it. You do not really need to change it to `func(Seq[Int])`.

Comment: By the way it's more precise to say that functions are contra-variant in terms of inputs or arguments and covariant in terms of return type.